# SQL Server Express 2005 Ambiguous column name

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

I am using SQL Server 2005 Express.

While I am executed the query I am getting wrong values

```
 select City, City2
    from
        sample.dbo.NameAddress 
    where
        FirstName like 'rama%' 
        and LastName like 'suresh%'
```

Getting same values for the both columns but actually they are different in DB,
When I see entire table it is showing exact values.

Comment: Could you post the table structure and some sample data?

Comment: There's nothing about that query that would cause the wrong data to show up--please post some more information.

Comment: blind shot but you most likely have a wrongly computed column in there.

Comment: @mgroves it wouldn't show wrong unless Rama is using SSMS (Rt Click => Open Table) to change data and it wasn't commited back to the database.  I agree with everyone else more information is needed here.

Comment: Hi all,
I am very sorry for the late reply,(I am not getting mails while updates are done).

Let me explain every thing.

I am using SQL Server 2005 Express.
I am accessing the database through hibernate to my java Program, 

I am running application successfully for every aspect,
Except this problem,
I have a table called NameAddress there are some column names like X, X2 

If I executed the query like above
in SQL Server management Studio Express, showing correct values

from hibernate I am getting the object in that both fields are getting same values
(But those are different in DB)

Thx